# Importing two variables from same module python

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I’m working on a Jupyter notebook, and am getting an error with this:

First, I import a variable from a module:

```
from data_generation.names import headers
```

which gives me no problem at all. Then a few cells below I try to make another import from the same module:

```
from data_generation.names import alldata_path
```

which gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-2663c91db1e3> in <module>
      1 from data_generation.data_preprocessing import data_to_csv
----> 2 from data_generation.names import alldata_path

ImportError: cannot import name 'alldata_path'
```

i got this 2 variables in the file|module names.py, who looks like this:

```
headers = {"V": ["FECHA", "MEDICION (V)"], "T":["FECHA", "MEDICION (T)"], "A":["FECHA", "MEDICION (A)"]}

alldata_path = ("C:/Users/Bastolo/Desktop/aritech/argomedo-solar-maintenance/data/all_data/")
```

I would appreciate any help on how to properly do this, since I want to keep a list (not list type) of variables if posible instead of using a dictionary to map all the variables I pretend to use.

EDIT: im getting this error just on the notebook, in IPython works fine... though id like to have it workin on the notebook

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting, try to proofread your messages for typos :).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
from module import a, b, c
```

Note that if you want to import everything you can just do

```
from module import *
```

Or import the module and access them with full path:

```
import module
module.a()
```

Comment: Maybe, the thing is im trying to make a distinction in the order of appearence of the variables, thinking of a proper way to document the code usage. 

Lets say im actually doing this: to make this thing happen (in the first cell) we need to import this variable. Then i make some other data management, and a few cells below i do: now for this thing to happen we need to import this another variable.

Comment: Side note: Please don't use `from module import *`. If you import multiple modules, you (or anyone who later works on your code) will have no idea which module things came from, and there might even be namespace conflicts.